# Jquery Canvas drawing inconsistent shapes

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have been scouring the internet and staring at this code for a while and I just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to make a chart in which the user inputs dimensions, and the canvas holds a chart in which the user can click on each box, and change the shading of that box. However for some reason, the boxes only fill up a portion of the chart.

my html file:

```
<body>
        <canvas id="box"></canvas>  
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('box');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        </script>
        ...
        <button type="button" id="buildDiagram">Go!</button>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/diagramFuncts.js"></script>  
</body>
```

diagramFuncts.js:

```
  $('#buildUry').click(function() {
    ....
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(252,252,252)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            //each box is 50 by 50 and the boxes populate the canvas from the upper left corner
            for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                for (j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                    ctx.fillRect(50*j, 50*i, 50, 50);       
                    ctx.strokeRect(50*j, 50*i, 50, 50);
                }
            }
  });
```

This code produces a canvas of the correct size, but it is not filled in correctly. For example, a 2 by 3 diagram is 100x150 pixels, but the inner boxes are of too small a size.

If anyone sees any bugs in my code, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you specify the size of the canvas? Like this: canvas.width = 800; canvas.height = 480;

Answer (score 1):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gg26Q/3/)

These two lines just needed i and j swapped.

```
ctx.fillRect(50 * i, 50 * j, 50, 50);
ctx.strokeRect(50 * i, 50 * j, 50, 50);
```

Columns (J) would be the second parameter for Y, and Rows (I), would be the first parameter for X.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('box');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rows = 2,
    cols = 3,
    width = rows*50,
    height = cols*50;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;


ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(252,252,252)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

//each box is 50 by 50 and the boxes populate the canvas from the upper left corner
for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
        ctx.fillRect(50 * i, 50 * j, 50, 50);
        ctx.strokeRect(50 * i, 50 * j, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Yep, nice catch.  In my experience the most difficult glitches to fix are those that run without throwing errors, but still misbehave.

Comment: Not exactly, because the width is determined by the number of columns, not the number of rows...

Comment: In the for loop given in the solution, the i and j should be switched. This flips the rectangle on to its side...